# Summarizing dataset with dplyr

Tags: r, list, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataset (QB2016) that I want to write r code that will summarize in one dataframe the number of times a player is listed as an observation but also list the "Opp" in the dataframe also.
For example from the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsjFb.png)

I want to get a summary of all players with total number of observations but also list of opp.
For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKip8.png)

To get the total observation per player I use

```
library(dplyr)
total <- QB2016 %>%
         group_by(Player) %>%
         summarize(Total = n())
```

but how do I add the list of "Opp" for each player observation?

Comment: People may have an easier time responding if you share the data you are using. You can use `dput` to do that. To keep it short, you can just share a section of your data, i.e.: `dput(head(QB2016, 20))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QB2016 %>%
   group_by(Player) %>%
   summarize(Total = n(), Opp = paste(Opp, collapse = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add 'Opp' to the group_by. Is that what you mean? This will return the player, opponent, and how many times they have faced.